# Tempo Search Autocomplete Nonsense Values

Tags: grafana, trace, open-telemetry, tempo, grafana-tempo

I am succesfully searching for traces on Tempo using Grafana. All my trace resources have at least these three labels `service`, `environment`, `instance`. In the dropdowns for these labels all the correct values show up *until* I restrict by one, then all the remaining resource values change to seemingly random numbers instead (but still the correct number of options).

This can't be to do with load as this is happening in my test environment with only one resource and my production environment (with many).

There are no error logs in my test environment whatsoever, so it isn't logging anything to do with this issue.

Has anyone experienced this/come across a solution. I'm completely stumped!

Comment: I'd recommend adding to the question how your variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Tempo recently fixed an issue that is likely related to this:

https://github.com/grafana/tempo/pull/3339